# Generate report using JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

Hi I have a jquery ajax receive action of the form.
Once the data from the form I can succeed in calling laporan_per_bulan.php file which the file contains code to extract data from ajax and print reports, according to the data.

However, the report does not appear?
I want a report that appeared in a new tab like in Google Chrome, or downloaded directly as other browsers, when ajax call success.

This is my ajax :

```
$('#save_report').click(function(e){
    ajax_cetak_laporan();
});

function ajax_cetak_laporan() {
    var bulan = $("#bulan option:selected").val();
    var kd_kelas = $("#kd_kelas option:selected").val();
    var kd_jur = $("#jur option:selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "../bayarspp/main/page/laporan_per_bulan.php",
        data: "{'bulan':'" + bulan+ "', 'kd_kelas':'" + kd_kelas + "', 'kd_jur':'" + kd_jur + "'}",
        success: function (html) {
            // do something here...
        }
    });
}
```

And this my **laporan_per_bulan.php** file :

```
<?php
...
$bulan = $_POST['bulan']; 
$kd_kelas = $_POST['kd_kelas']; 
$jur = $_POST['kd_jur'];

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(35, 0, 'Bulan');
$pdf->Cell(5, 0, ':');
$pdf->Cell(70, 0, $bulan);
$pdf->Ln(4);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(35, 3, 'Kelas');
$pdf->Cell(5, 3, ':');
$pdf->Cell(70, 3, $kd_kelas);
$pdf->Ln(10); 

#output file PDF
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this in ajax response.....

Comment: what is the response type? html or json?

Comment: I don't know what the best response type. But how about i choose html?

Comment: Looks like you are outputting pdf; so I assume your headers will set to pdf?

Comment: A suggestion: Instead of posting it via ajax; why don't you just post as a normal html form ? Then in php you can just print the output (process as pdf in your case) based on your post values.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and store the pdf on the server like "/folder_name/uniqueID.pdf" on ajax request.

Return the uniqueID as ajax response(EXP:{"success:true","uniqueID:121212"}). Then write on the ajax success section

```
  success: function(data) {
      if(data.success == true){                    
        window.location.href = site_url+path to pdf/+data.uniqueID.pdf;
      }
  }
```

or you cab do the following

```
success: function(data) {
   if(data.success == true){                    
     window.location.href  = site_url+path to pdf/download.php?uniqueID=data.uniqueID;
    }
  }
```

download.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['uniqueID'])){
   $uniqueID= $_REQUEST['uniqueID'];
   $downname="downloading_filename.pdf";
   download($uniqueID,$downname);
}else{
    //return to any url or die;
}

function download($uniqueID,$downname){
        $cwd=getcwd();
        $filedestination = $cwd."/".$uniqueID.".pdf";

        if (file_exists($filedestination)) {    
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$downname);
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filedestination));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($filedestination);
                ignore_user_abort(true);
                if (connection_aborted()) {
                        unlink($filedestination);
                }
                if(file_exists($filedestination)){
                        unlink($filedestination);
                }
                exit;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this jquery plugin, that do this job by displaying hidden fields.

I checked it at all major browsers.

Url here:
http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/